# How do I access the Magento system config?

Tags: magento2

I've just recently installed Magento 2.0.2 (I'm new to Magento) and have been following some tutorials and documentation to do it.

I've noticed that a lot of screenshots and tutorials ask to go to **System > Configuration** but when I log into my Magento admin, there is no such option (screenshot below). I tried to go into Web Setup Wizard where is asked me for a public/private access key which I generated and entered, now when I go into the Web Setup Wizard, it just shows this (screenshot 2 below).

I don't know what to do, can anyone please enlighten me?

[image: magento 2.0.2 system menu]
[image: magento 2.0.2 system config]

Comment: Go to `Stores > Configuration.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system configuration have been moved to Stores, so its now

> Stores > Configuration.